# Storing Values after running GoalSeek

Tags: excel, vba

I am running GoalSeek for several scenarios with a single output, B95.

After each scenario runs, I need to store the value of the cell that GoalSeek was changing, B4.

This value needs to be stored in cells P97, P98 and P99 (three values for three scenarios).

With my current macro, I can see that GoalSeek is working but the value is not stored and "False" is entered into cells P97, P98 and P99.

'tolerance' is a precaution in case GoalSeek does not find an exact match. (I'm dealing with percentages and would like a tolerance of ±1%.)

I know the issue is somewhere in the first half of the If statement. I want to store the value GoalSeek finds before moving on to the next Goal Seek scenario.

```vb
Sub Button1_Click()

Dim k As Integer
Dim PurchasePrice As Integer
Const tolerance As Long = 0.01

For k = 87 To 89
    Range("B95").GoalSeek Goal:=Cells(k, "O"), ChangingCell:=Range("B4")
      
    If Cells(95, "B").Value <= Cells(k, "O") + tolerance And Cells(95, "B").Value >= Cells(k, "O") - tolerance Then
        PurchasePrice = Range("B4").Value
        Range(Cells(k, "P")).Value = PurchasePrice
    Else
        Cells(k, "P") = False
    End If
        
Next k

End Sub
```

Comment: It appears the `Else Cells(k, "P") = False` is firing, indicating either/both conditions in your `If` statement are evaluating to `False`. Have you stepped through the code and checked your conditions are evaluating the way you expect them to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a basic bug in:

```
Range(Cells(k, "P")).Value = PurchasePrice.
```

If you want to keep your code as is, you need to change that to

```
Cells(k, "P") = PurchasePrice
```

Otherwise, your logic seems sound. For testing I rewrote to 'my preferred' syntax (see below). It is somewhat simpler (helping me see it all clearer).
However, basic logic is yours (net of the bug).

```
Sub Button1_Click()

    Dim in1%
    Const bdTolerance# = 0.01

    For in1 = 87 To 89
    
        With Range("B95")
            .GoalSeek Goal:=Cells(in1, "O"), ChangingCell:=Range("B4")
    
            If .Value <= Cells(in1, "O") + bdTolerance And .Value >= Cells(in1, "O") - bdTolerance Then
                Cells(in1, "P") = Range("B4")
            Else
                Cells(in1, "P") = False
            End If
        End With
            
    Next in1

End Sub
```

Separately, you say in your text that you want a tolerance of ±1%.
However, you are adding and subtracting literal 0.01 (not 1%).
To apply as a percentage, change the test to:

```
If .Value <= Cells(in1, "O") * (1 + bdTolerance) And _
    .Value >= Cells(in1, "O") * (1 - bdTolerance) Then
```

Lastly, you say in your text "This value needs to be stored in cells P97, P98 and P99 (3 different values for 3 scenarios)". However, your code is getting from and storing to rows 87 To 89. To change to rows 97 to 99, change the For values per:

```
For in1 = 97 To 99
```

All up, assuming your descriptive text is accurate and the code is not, the consolidated solution is:

```
Sub Button1_Click()

    Dim in1%
    Const bdTolerance# = 0.01

    For in1 = 97 To 99
    
        With Range("B95")
            .GoalSeek Goal:=Cells(in1, "O"), ChangingCell:=Range("B4")
    
            If .Value <= Cells(in1, "O") * (1 + bdTolerance) And _
                .Value >= Cells(in1, "O") * (1 - bdTolerance) Then
                Cells(in1, "P") = Range("B4")
            Else
                Cells(in1, "P") = False
            End If
        End With
            
    Next in1

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you very much. This is extremely helpful. I ended up with a slightly different solution that yielded the results I needed, but your explanation answers questions I would have inevitably run into down the road.

Comment: Good oh. Then could you perhaps mark this as the answer. Just saves others like me having to read all this to find out it's solved.